Does Mach's principle imply anisotropic mass?
Mach suggested, among other conditions, that Newton’s gravitational constant G is a dynamical field and that inertial mass is affected by the global distribution of matter.
Steven Weinberg suggests in this book "Gravitation and Cosmology" that Mach's principle implies anisotropic inertial mass, which is ruled out by observations. I quote:

The issue between Mach and Einstein can be drawn by asking whether in fact the presence of large nearby masses does affect the laws of motion, other than by determining the inertial frames? Cocconi and Salpeter pointed out that there is a large mass near us, the Milky Way galaxy, and that Mach's principle would suggest slight differences in inertial mass when a particle is accelerated toward or away from the galactic center.

But there are models following Mach's conditions that leave inertial mass as a scalar, and thus, isotropic. In particular, Hans Jurgen Treder's works based on the Riemann potential (in contrast to most of the other Machian approaches based on Weber's potential), implies scalar (isotropic) inertial masses in contrast to vector/tensor (anisotropic) ones.
Does Mach's principle always imply anisotropic inertial mass as suggested by Weinberg?

What did Mach write that suggested that he modelled inertial mass as a vector or, say, a tensor, as implied by your question? Does Weinberg throw any light on this?

Mach never wrote a testable theory nor even a mathematical framework or formalism. So different people have different opinions on whether a theory implements it or not. Such claims wind up just being opinion.

See Dale's comment, and a few of my older ones that I can't find at the moment; Mach's principle means basically nothing. It's thirty-something different interpretations of a thing people (unverifiably) claim Mach once said that turns out to be false under any reasonable construction of known physics. As such I'm VTC: Opinion-Based given that Mach's principle is funamentally opinion-based.

@MoziburUllah Mach suggested that Newton’s gravitational constant G is a dynamical field and that inertial mass is affected by the global distribution of matter. I edit the question with what Weinberg states in his book.

@Dale The Machian conditions to be satisfied by a theory complying with Mach's principle were defined by H. Bondi. See https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9607009 for reference

@controlgroup A Machian theory has to satisfy Machian conditions. Bondi defined these conditions here: https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9607009 You can read what Mach wrote, so I dont think his claims are unverifiable.

The abstract of that paper: "We respond to a recent paper by Rindler on the 'Anti–Machian' nature of the Lense–Thirring effect. We remark that his conclusion
depends crucially on the particular formulation of Mach’s principle
used." So the Universe is Machian, under some interpretation of what Mach's principle actually is. Bondi et. al. defined more than 11 different ways you could interpret the idea of "mass out there determines inertia here". Which one is correct? Which one do you refer to? Which one did Mach originally intend? All of these questions are unanswered.

@IndependentPhysics that paper strongly supports my point. From the abstract "his conclusion depends crucially on the particular formulation of Mach's principle". Meaning that Mach's principle is not clear enough to admit a single formulation, nor even a class of equivalent formulations. Which formulation should be chosen is just an opinion. If you want to make this question non-opinion-based then you need to choose a specific formulation and limit your question to that specific formulation. Weinburg's opinion would be that Treder's work is not Machian, while Treder has the opposite opinion

I think it's a shame that the discussion of Mach's principle leads to such statements: „ Mach's principle was one of the ideas that guided Einstein in the development of the general theory of relativity (sic!). However, it later proved to be incompatible with some concrete formulations of Mach's principle. In 1949, Kurt Gödel constructed a solution to the equations of ART with a rotating universe that blatantly violated Mach's principle (Gödel universe), but it was not realistic and made time travel possible. (from the German Wikipedia) That makes me laugh and a little sad.

@Dale Treder's work is Machian since I believe it satisfies all conditions (and I especifically called them conditions and not formulations) of Mach's principle defined by Bondi.

If in your opinion Treder’s work is Machian then I believe you have your own answer

Weinberg's argument is that since (as per Mach) the inertial mass depends on the presence of surrounding masses elsewhere, so it must also on the distribution of those surrounding masses. He further qualifies that the influence is more than just (possibly) determining the local free fall acceleration - it determines the very rest mass itself. Since we are not at the gravitational center of our galaxy, terrestrial measurements should reflect this, providing a test.

But there are models following Mach's conditions that leave inertial mass as a scalar, and thus, isotropic

What distribution of 'far away background of stars' do these models assume for applying Mach's principle? Whether or not Weinberg's test applies depends on that.

If inertial mass is a scalar, even if it depends on the potential of the distribution of the rest of masses in the universe, it has no preferred direction and thus, it is isotropic, and those test which look for a particular direction (i.e., the center of the milky way) provide no refutation of the Machian dependence of inertial mass and background distribution of masses in the universe.

@IndependentPhysics If the remote distribution is non-uniform/anisotropic, the local effects must reflect that too else there is no meaning in saying that there is a non-uniform distribution. Since the local effect is entirely that of determining the inertial mass, there must be directional dependence (there can be no distance dependence since the background is far away [what would that even mean]). I suspect that scalarity couples to an isotropic background in these models, which makes the expt. inapplicable to them.

In these models, inertial mass is a scalar depending on the sum of gravitational potentials of local and global masses. Why must there be directional dependence with the local?
